# Alamofire: 'The request timed out' within 1 second regardless of timoutIntervalForRequest

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to engage Alamofire in my app and faced the following problem in the first request (which I managed to make successfully with `URLSession`).

When performing a request, within 1-2 seconds I see `-1001 The request timed out` in the log, although I set a relatively long interval for the session.

This is `HttpSession` atm:

```
class HttpSession {

    static let instance = HttpSession()
    let sessionManager: SessionManager?

    private init() {
        let conf = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        conf.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
        sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: conf)
    }
}
```

Here I make the request:

```
HttpSession.instance.sessionManager!.request(url, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("YAA!")
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
        break
    }
}
```

One odd thing to mention: When I tried to print time before and after to see the time difference, the values were indeed 30 seconds different, though in real life it took 1-2 seconds. I tested it only on simulator.
To print seconds I used the following snippet twice, before the request and in the response:

```
let date: Date = Date()
print(Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date))
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I was wrong as the request indeed timed out each time once the interval has passed. Most of my tests were done with 8 seconds interval and I didn't notice that the timeout log appeared much later.

Anyway, the problem was with 'parameters' parameter; when putting an empty dictionary `parameters: [:]` it always timed out, and when replaced with `nil` it began to work as expected. I find it strange since in the first comment in [this issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508) it is stated that both are supposed to work the same way, and anyhow this type of error is not related to this issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the NSURLSessionConfiguration source code you will find these comments:

> /* default timeout for requests.  This will cause a timeout if no data
>   is transmitted for the given timeout value, and is reset whenever data
>   is transmitted. */   public var timeoutIntervalForRequest:
>   NSTimeInterval
>
> /* default timeout for requests.   This will cause a timeout if a
>   resource is not able to be retrieved within a given timeout. */
>   public var timeoutIntervalForResource: NSTimeInterval

You need to set this value as well:

```
conf.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
```

Comment: I tried to set them both, but faced the same issue.